# Framework similar to Spring Data JPA or Hades for CDI or EJB?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, cdi

I am looking for a framework that reduce the nessasary ammount of boilerplate code to write a DAO in JEE6 standart stack (EJB 3.1 or CDI).

In Spring are two frameworks [Hades](http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/show/hades) and [Spring Data JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa), both provide an approach to define JPA finder just by writing an Interface but no implementation. Is there something similar for EJB 3.1 or CDI?

Comment: Hades and Spring Data JPA are the same thing, same author, just that Spring Data JPA is the new name

Comment: @DataNucleus: I know, but that both are almost the same, but I mentions both in the question for the case that someone only konws one of them.

Comment: Aren't both of those NoSQL aggregation apis?

Comment: @LightGuard no, not really, only the Spring Data JPA super project abstract from different data sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ctpconsulting.github.com/query/1.0.0.Alpha3/index.html is a good project. You can also watch Apache DeltaSpike (currently in incubator) for an extension in the coming months.

Comment: CDI Query Module is what I was looking for, unfortunately it is a Alpha version at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

To quote [Spring Data JPA documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpd.misc.cdi-integration):

> As of version 1.1.0 Spring Data JPA ships with a custom CDI extension that allows using the repository abstraction in CDI environments.